# PHP - Avoiding Duplicate value from Cloned ComboBox

Tags: javascript, php, combobox, duplicates, jquery-clone

So I have a combobox (see picture) --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS8Fq.png) that get its value from sql SELECT, these combobox could be cloned with the javascript I made :

```
$("#addBahan").click(function() {
      $('#form_block_bahan').append(selectHtml);

  });

$("#form_block_bahan").on('click', 'input[name="remove"]', function() {
     $(this).closest(".form_bahan").remove();
 });
```

My question is, how do you prevent each cloned combobox to have the same value as the others? Thanks in advance and I'm sorry, I cannot put my code in here. I don't know why it always fails. And sorry for my bad English ^^

Comment: Please post code instead of screenshots :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i've tried it, but whenever i do, its alaways failed to become a code line, juts a plain text. sorry for bad english

Comment: Put some spaces ( i think atleast 4) , before all lines of code and then post as code. You have been able to copy jquery functions, just like that